Firestore query with OR clause throwing error: Value for argument "fieldPath" is not a valid field path
I'm trying to perform a query with an OR clause using the Firebase node SDK.
import { and, or, where } from "firebase/firestore"
import { adminDB } from "./firebase/firebaseAdmin"

// Build the query
let q = adminDB.collection("posts")

if (condition) {
q = q.where(
      or(
        where("author.id", "==", "myId"),
        and(
          where("is_draft", "==", false),
          where("trashed_at", "==", null),
          where("is_disapproved", "==", false)
        )
      )
    )
}

const postsSnap = await q.limit(10).get()

This gives me the error

Error: Value for argument "fieldPath" is not a valid field path. Paths can only be specified as strings or via a FieldPath object.

and points to the where() clause within the if block as the culprit. ...But I don't understand why.?
StackOverflow gods, please help me understand where I went wrong. Thanks!

Rookie mistake.. I was using the wrong JavaScript web SDK (d'oh!)
Fixed it like this
import { Filter } from "firebase-admin/firestore"
import { adminDB } from "./firebase/firebaseAdmin"

// Build the query
let q = adminDB.collection("posts")

if (condition) {
q = q.where(
      Filter.or(
        Filter.where("author.id", "==", "myId"),
        Filter.and(
          Filter.where("is_draft", "==", false),
          Filter.where("trashed_at", "==", null),
          Filter.where("is_disapproved", "==", false)
        )
      )
    )
}

const postsSnap = await q.limit(10).get()

